# Não consigo mais rodar minha aplicação para ios

Tags: ios, visual-studio, debug, release

Eu antes conseguia rodar tranquilamente a minha aplicação, só que agora pouco tinha sumido da lista debug a opção de rodar no ios ficou apenas android e uwp. agora voltou a aparecer só que não consigo mais rodar. aparece essa mensagem de erro no visual studio, ja tentei reicinia a o visual, reparei ele tambem e até testei em outra maquina o meu projeto mas da o mesmo erro, ja tentei fazer o que a imagem pede também.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Depois de tanto procurar descobri que fui o primeiro a ter esse problema. consegui solucionar.
adicionei a solução um novo projeto chamado NewiOS seguindo as instruções para isso do site http://www.randrade.net/2017/06/28/adicionado-manualmente-um-projeto-ios-na-solucao-xamarin-forms/
depois testei o projeto iOS antigo e continuava com o problema mas o novo rodava perfeitamente então apaguei o projeto antigo da solução e fiquei só com o NewiOS

Deixo aqui a solução caso mais alguém venha passar por isso.